# AudioKit.start() Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: audiokit

I'm following the Hello World tutorial Video on http://audiokit.io/downloads/

As soon as I add the line `AudioKit.start()` in the `ViewController.swift` I get the error:

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled"

I downloaded fresh AudioKit 4.1 and dragged in frameworks.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The example projects have been updated, but not the video.  You probably want this instead of "try!":

```
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit did not start!")
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

All I needed was to change the line:  AudioKit.start()

to

try! AudioKit.start()

problem solved.   This was not in the video tutorial. Apparently something changed with Xcode or swift or  AudioKit . (all are different versions that in the video)

Comment: The videos have not been edited since this change, but all the examples and playgrounds and release notes do show this.

Comment: And, banging try is not quite as good as the answer above, a little more dangerous.